# React Testing Library can't find my self-closing tag in a react fragment, and just renders <body/>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsx, react-testing-library

I've got a component like this:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ foo }) => (
  <>
    <div>
    <Header />
      {foo}
    </div>
    <div data-testid="self-closing-tag" className={styles.break} />
  </>
)
```

(n.b. React should handle the div being a self-closing tag, whereas without react that's not valid html)

I've written a test that renders my component `<div data-testid="foo" />` for the `foo` prop and runs `expect(screen.getByTestId('foo')).toBeInTheDocument();` which passes. If I use `screen.debug` in that test, I get the fully rendered DOM.

But when I write a test for the self closing tag, like so: `expect(screen.getByTestId('self-closing-tag')).toHaveClass('break');` I get:

> Unable to get element by: `[data-testid="self-closing-tag"]`

and where I'd expect it to print out the fully rendered DOM, it just prints `<body />`.

If I put the expect assertion for the self-closing tag in the test for 'foo', they both pass.

```js
describe('<My Component />', () => {
  beforeEach(<MyComponent foo={<div data-testid="foo" />} />);
  it('renders foo', () => {
    expect(screen.getByTestId('foo')).toBeInTheDocument();
    // expect(screen.getByTestId('self-closing-tag')).toHaveClass('break'); -- this passes if uncommmented!
  };
  it('renders the self closing tag', () => {
    expect(screen.getByTestId('self-closing-tag')).toHaveClass('break'); // cannot find element, prints '<body />' as the DOM.
  })
})
```

I can obviously shove everything in the same `it` statement, but I'd rather not if possible. I'd also like to understand whats going on.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That´s because `toHaveClass` expects an arg with the class name, you can check the docs [here](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveclass).

So, your test could be:

```js
expect(screen.getByTestId("self-closing-tag")).toHaveClass("XX class name you expect XX");
```

or if you just want to check if the element has the attribute class

```js
expect(screen.getByTestId("self-closing-tag")).toHaveAttribute("class");
```

Comment: Oops, I manually copied the code over wrong, I've updated/corrected the question now. However, your answer wouldn't explain why a) it passes when run after a different test in the same `it` block b) why it can't find the element, not that it finds the  element but it doesn't have the class

Comment: maybe you are missing something or i didnt get what you want. But take a look into this [codesample](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-tohaveclass-test-example-wsmsf1?file=/src/Example.spec.js), perhaps it help you. * Just check the tests tab.

Comment: how do I run the tests? If you delete the 'hasAttributes' one, does it still pass for you?

Comment: There is a `Tests`  tab, next to the `Browser` tab from codesandbox. Just click in the tab and the tests will start to run. * And yes, all tests pass successfully.